# multiple marker doesn't show up in google map using angualrjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

```
.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, Markers) {
var username = window.localStorage.getItem('username');
var id_user = window.localStorage.getItem('id_user');
console.log(username);
console.log(id_user);
document.getElementById('usernameArea').innerHTML = username;

var map = null;
```

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.977467753377946, 112.63355255126953);

```
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
        //var tes = new google.maps.Latlang();

        //var tes = map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
        var tes = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
        console.log(tes.lat(), tes.lng());
        //console.log(tes.lng());
        window.localStorage.setItem('lat',tes.lat());
        window.localStorage.setItem('lng',tes.lng());

        var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
            map: map,
            title: "My Location"
        });
         loadMarkers();

    });

    $scope.map = map;

});
```

function loadMarkers(){

```
  //Get all of the markers from our Markers factory
  Markers.getMarkers().then(function(markers){
    console.log("Markers: ", markers);

    var records = markers.data.markers;
    console.log(records.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {

      var record = records[i];   
      var markerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(record.latitude, record.longitude);
      console.log(record.latitude);
      // Add the markerto the map
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          setMap: map,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: markerPos
      });

      var infoWindowContent = "<h4>" + record.name + "</h4>";          
      addInfoWindow(marker, infoWindowContent, record);

    }

  });
```

}

function addInfoWindow(marker, message, record) {

```
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: message
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
```

}

})
[this is the result, the marker which get latitude and longitude from database doesn't show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSb93.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have seen the mistake, when you create the marker in your loadMarkers() function you have this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      setMap: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: markerPos
});
```

You are using as key setMap and it's map, so the code should be:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: markerPos
});
```